# Rails 3 specific controller for admin renders the default 'show' view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-inheritance

that's my problem, I'm trying to implement a separate admin layer in my app following this good tutorial: http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1

Everything works smooth but in views/backend/items/index.html.erb, with the common:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', item %>
```

I'm geting the default application view: views/items/show instead of backend/views/items/show

The call to the index page is being made from the backend/items_controller but it seems that the Rails 3 view inheritance is skiping the first part in the chain.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tutorial shown, should it be:

```
link_to 'show', resource_path(resource)
```

?